# SWIFT Keyboard overlaps content

Tags: swift, notifications, uiscrollview

On my loginViewController there is a **textField** and the **button** for searching. I want to make sure that when entering text in the textField my interface is not overlapped by the keyboard, but scrolled to the size of this keyboard and there was access to all the elements. For this I wrote this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(kbDidShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(kbDidHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func kbDidShow(notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
        let kdFrameSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        (self.view as! UIScrollView).contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height + kdFrameSize.height)
        (self.view as! UIScrollView).scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: kdFrameSize.height, right: 0)
    }

    @objc func kbDidHide() {
        (self.view as! UIScrollView).contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height)
    }
```

When I run the application I have a side view of the scrollbar, but the interface itself does not scroll.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try using IQKeyboardManager this will do your job automatically
Link - https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

You just need to add this line in AppDelegate
All of the textfield will be adjusted automatically, in every view.

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the content offset rather than setting the contentSize.

```
 @objc func kbDidShow(notification: Notification) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
    let kdFrameSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    (self.view as! UIScrollView).contentOffset.y +=  kdFrameSize.size.height
    (self.view as! UIScrollView).scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: kdFrameSize.height, right: 0)
}
```